# Python TKinter displaying the list in sequence number

Tags: python, tkinter

I am not able to get expected output in tkinter.

```
readdata = [{"ID": 0xF162,"Description": "Read anything "},
                 {"ID": 0xEE17,"Description": "Read nothing Status"},
                   {"ID": 0xEE18,"Description": "Read one word"}]

    for readdta in readdata:

                  temp_text = '{0:04X} - {1}'.format(readdta['ID'], readdta['Description'])
          Label(self.top, text=temp_text).pack()
```

I wanted output to be display in tkinter as below: without changing the list.

```
1. 0xf162 Read anything
2. 0xEE17 Read nothing Status
3. 0xEE18 Read one word
```

with Number
1.
2.
3.
at beginning

Answer (score 1):

With the assumption that your code works(had some formatting issues) you can change your loop to this:

```
for i, readdta in enumerate(readdata, start=1):
    #adds the enumerate statement which act as a counter
    temp_text = '{0}. {1:04X} - {2}'.format(i, readdta['ID'], readdta['Description'])
    Label(self.top, text=temp_text).pack()
```

[see this for more information on how to use enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate)